# Check order of dimensions of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D volume and I want the order of the dimensions in memory to be like this:

```
x changes fastest, then y, then z
```

So if the volume dimensions are `(depth, height, width)` then the first `width` elements should be the first row of the first slice. Followed by `width` elements of the second row of the first slice, then the third row of the first slice... This would go on for `height` rows for the first slice. Then this process would repeat again for all `depth` slices.

To give a concrete example, let's say I have the following data for a 3x3 volume.

Slice 0:

```
[  1,  2,  3 ]
[  4,  5,  6 ]
[  7,  8,  9 ]
```

Slice 1:

```
[ 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 13, 14, 15 ]
[ 16, 17, 18 ]
```

Slice 2:

```
[ 19, 20, 21 ]
[ 22, 23, 24 ]
[ 25, 26, 27 ]
```

Then I want the in memory data to look like:

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ... 27 ]

How should I check if my data is ordered like this, and if it isn't how should I order it?

Comment: What is `first slice` for you? Better add a sample case and explain the expected output?

Comment: Are you talking about a 3d array, or a 2d array with 3 columns (n points defined by 3 (x,y,z) values)?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How do you define slice? Is this for memory coalescing? What is the shape of the original 3D volume? etc...

Comment: I updated my example. I hope you see what I mean

Comment: You can use np.reshape( input, (numberOfElements) ) and check if the order looks like [1,2,3,4....27]. You can then use np.swapaxes to rearrange the axes. Knowing how your data is stored though would be more helpful.

Comment: Currently I can access each slice like this volume[:, :, z] where z is the slice I need.